# How to access data payload in a backgrounded app after user taps the FCM notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending an FCM notification message *with data payload* to an Android app being in *background* by POSTing the following JSON content to the URL https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
    "notification":{"body":"Alexander performs a move!"},
    "data":{"gid":1},
    "to":"c0k6VWNdTSo:APA91bETXBGasi-X6-VGWTWYtSv3u1NETwqblEW1uoE1MswFkb9-Yf-rlVEGbaPD4gLQh3JLWIAyQRvAYNcdtmZLgFDhUEnXwFpVQSNFFr0xl47sK9FnvRY9J6JLX2P34UvpuCbZYBZ4"
}
```

And receive a confirmation about successful delivery by the FCM backend:

```
{
    "multicast_id":7103158248293730650,
    "success":1,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[{"message_id":"0:1514203203800219%c7d12ab4c7d12ab4"}]
}
```

After that I tap the notification at the top of Android phone and my app is being launched (it was in *background* before):

[image: debugger screenshot]

Then I am trying to access the "gid" value, which I have set in the "data" part of the notification by the code in `onCreate` method:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int gid = i.getIntExtra("gid", 0);
    if (gid > 0) {
        // TODO show GameFragment
    }
```

Unfortunately, there is no such EXTRA (you can also see in the above debugger screenshot, that there are no extras passed with the intent for some reason).

What am I missing here please? According to the [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) (emphasis mine):

> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the
>   notification tray, and only **handle the data payload when the user taps
>   on the notification.**

How can I access the "data" part after tapping the notification, isn't it passed as intent extra?

Comment: please post your onMessageReceived method’s code

Comment: The `onMessageReceived` method is not called, because I am sending *mixed* push notification to an app being in the *background*. My question is how to handle the "data" part, after user taps the notification.

Comment: I'm seeing the gid does exists in i.extras if you look closely in debug pic above which is 1 from firebase that you sent

Comment: I mean check in image
Bottom right box -> below main activity there is "i" variable which you have expanded to debug and in which there is extras and in that line you see gid=1 i guess you're receiving the gid in activity bundle , what is the value of KEY_GID ?

Comment: Yes, you're probably correct, this is my value. The `KEY_GID` String is just "gid".

Comment: Got correct value?

Comment: Yes, I've got the value by `int gid = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("gid"));` thank you. Please write the answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

the notification part is totally handled by google.And also there’s no event of notification click.By default on notification click the launcher activity will be opened and its totally managed by google.So you have to manage it on launcher Activity by checking data part.

> Data part handling

As data part is totally depend on you that how did u send this from sever

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
```

Comment: Ibrahim, if you look at the debugger screenshot in my question, the `mData` is null (even though I have sent `"data":{"gid":1}`). So I can not call `getData()` on the launching intent. Or what do you mean by the `remoteMessage.getData()`? As I have commented before, the `onMessageReceived()` method of my app in background is not supposed to be called, this is explained in [the FCM doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages).